# Python: Change my Automated Browser Timezone

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to change my browser timezone in a Selenium Web browser execution, I tried different approaches but most of what I get only changes certain values of my timezone execution but not the browser itself,

My chromedriver:

```
WEB_DRIVER_URL = 'http://localhost:4445/wd/hub'
```

This is my current function:

```
import time, os

def change_timezone(tmezone='Etc/GMT-5',):
    os.environ['TZ'] = tmezone
    time.tzset()
    print(time.strftime('%X %x %Z'))
```

The issue here is that when I check ([using this site](https://www.doileak.com/)) if my timezone and my browser TZ are aligned I get the following result:

[image]

Comment: I think timezone that the browser uses is at the OS level. May depend on which browser you're using.

Comment: It is a selenium webdriver called from the web, WEB_DRIVER_URL = 'http://localhost:4445/wd/hub'